# how can I convert JSON text to JSON object?

Tags: javascript, json

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to parse JSON in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935632/how-to-parse-json-in-javascript)

```
{
 "data": [
          {
             "name": "JoongBum Lee",
             "id": "526210623"
          },
          {
             "name": "\uc774\uc778\uaddc",
             "id": "560021193"
          },
          {
             "name": "SunAh Han",
             "id": "589325702"
          }
    ]
}
```

i have JSON data and I want to convert this data in to javacript object

Comment: "Convert" (from string) is called "parse".. Use `JSON.parse(JSONString);`

Comment: Possible duplicate of search functionality and related section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`JSON.parse`<sup>[MDN]</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse). It was introduced in ECMAScript 5 and is therefore not supported by <=IE7. You can find a [JSON library](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js) to fill in support for older browsers, or if you use jQuery you can use [`$.parseJSON`<sup>[jQuery docs]</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/).

```
var str = '"data": [ { "name": "JoongBum Lee", "id": "526210623" }, { "name": "\uc774\uc778\uaddc", "id": "560021193" }, { "name": "SunAh Han", "id": "589325702" } ] }';
var obj = JSON.parse(str);
```

Comment: sorry but error occurs document.getelementbyld is null or not object

Comment: @SukKyuSun That error must be in some other section of your code, because parsing JSON has nothing to do with the `document.getElementById` function.

Answer (score 0):

```
var dataString = "{/* SOMETHING */}"
var obj = eval("(" + dataString + ")");
```

Comment: This would work, but not recommend.

Comment: sure JSON.parse(str) is better, but not supported by older browsers.